# Send manipulated/own Created response to Client from Server

Tags: node.js, express, svn

Iam using
https://github.com/peteward44/node-svn-ultimate
And it is not developed with Promises. But I want to send the Result whether Success or Error to the Client from NodeJs Server.
Normally it goes this way

```
    // Client -> AngularJs Request
    svn()
    {
      this.$http.post(...)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        },err=>{
          console.log(err);
        });
    }  
**Server**  
//  index.js
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/svn', controller.svn);//the route to use

module.exports = router;    


//controller.js
function respondWithResult(res, statusCode) {//respond to client
  statusCode = statusCode || 200;
  return function(entity) {
    if (entity) {
      res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
    }
  };
}
...
export function svn(req, res) {
      return DB.find({...})//Sequelize Query
    })//returning res as promise
    .then(res => {
        svnUltimate.commands.commit(..., (err, success) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log('commit error')
                    console.log(err)
                  } else {
                    console.log(success);
                })
        return res;
      })
    })
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

It is now Responding the result of the Database Query but I want that it Response the SVN Result.
Tried Several things like

```
svnUltimate.commands.commit(..., (err, success) => {
                      if (err) {
                        res=err;
                      } else {
                        //res=success;// answer was still the DB query
                        //return success; // no output
                        //res.status(404).send('crazy');// is no function
                        //res.status = 404 //no output
                        // res.writeHeader()// no function
                      })
            return res;
          })
```

How can I respond to Client with the Result of the SVN Command Result?
Modify the `res` of Sequelize?
Write somehow own Response ?
Or is there a SVN Package with Promises?

Using only
NodeJs 6.9.5
Express 4.0
Sequelize 3.28

Answer (score 0):

To return data I use the following methods.

```
res.status = 200;
res.json({myData: "example");
```

If you have an error you would want to send something like this:

```
res.status = 400;
res.JSON({message: "error. Invalid request"})
```

You need to decide what type of data you're going to return from your webserver. The above example uses JSON and is best suited for a JavaScript stack.